# Paperclip configurations | Old Attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, compression, paperclip

I recently changed my Paperclip configurations:

**New Configs:**

```
  has_attached_file :scr, :styles => { :index => "215x165#", :show => "900" },
                    processors: [:thumbnail, :compression],
                    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/png"] }
```

**Old Configs:**

```
has_attached_file :scr, :styles => { :index => "215x165#
```

For Showing the Pictures i need on my App i use the `:show` attribute.

**The Problem is** that my app has already a lot of pictures and upon changing the configs the pictures are not longer visible (Cause the cropping and configuration is done when uploading).

Is there a way to Re-Save those Pictures ?

I tried

```
Screen.find_each(&:save)
```

where "Screen" the pictures, but it didn't work.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Screen`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't even know there was such a command. The right command is `rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=Screen`

Comment: on heroku i'm getting `Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.` any idea ?